# Count groups and display only those with 2 or more results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, title
  FROM [Scyk].[dbo].[Threads]
  where cnt > 1
  group by Title
```

This query is wrong but I don't know how to fix it, how to display only groups with 2 or more? I am using MS SQL

Update: If I also want to count groups, how do I do it? I did something like this but it didn't work:

```
select COUNT(*)
from
(SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, title FROM [Scyk].[dbo].[Threads] group by Title having COUNT(*) > 0)
where cnt = 2
```

Comment: @zerkms: yeah, but you guys are faster than google ;)

Comment: that way you never become a smarter person. If it's fine for you that after solving `1 + 1` task you need help for solving `1 + 2`, then - go for it and continue asking trivial questions indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, title
  FROM [Scyk].[dbo].[Threads]
  group by Title
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The Where Clause Filter the results Before doing any Aggregates on the rows. Having Filters Rows After the aggregates. Also you cannot use Alias in Having Clause you have to use the actual Function.
**Eidt**

 for your next query your missing Alias for your sub-query the rest looks fine

```
select COUNT(*)
from
(SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, title 
FROM [Scyk].[dbo].[Threads] 
group by Title 
having COUNT(*) > 0) q
where cnt = 2
```

Comment: Having works great, thank you! Could you look at my update please?

Comment: When you have a sub-query in from clause you have to Alias it otherwise it will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Having](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) keyword:

So your query would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, title
  FROM [Scyk].[dbo].[Threads]
  where cnt > 1
  group by Title
  having count(*) > 1
```